# A new user is added to wheel group but not showing in wheel group even though added

Tags: rhel, sudo

I'm using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)`. I created a new user with

```
useradd igwuser
```

I added it to wheel group using the command

```
usermod -g wheel igwuser
```

Now I can perform operations with `sudo` for `igwuser`. Problem I'm facing is, still igwuser is not shown in wheel group.

```
$ grep wheel /etc/group
wheel:x:10:secadmin
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given the `igwuser` user `wheel` as their primary login group.  The `/etc/group` database only lists secondary group memberships.

If you now do `getent passwd igwuser`, you will see `wheel` listed as their login group (the fourth `:`-delimited field will be the GID of `wheel`, probably `0`).

To add the user to the `wheel` group in such a way that it is a secondary group for the user, you should have used

```
usermod -a -G wheel igwuser
```

This appends (`-a`) the `wheel` group to the secondary groups of the user.

See also `man usermod` on your system.

You could also have added the user to `wheel` with the `useradd` command at the same time as you created the user:

```
useradd ...options... -G wheel igwuser
```

See `man useradd` on your system.

Comment: You may also add the user `igwuser`to the group `wheel` using `gpasswd -a igwuser wheel`.